# When type in my textbox my list view filters fine. however when i erase some letters (backspace) the list does not update

Tags: java, android, listview

I have been banging my head against this one for two days on and off.

I tried to use getfilter.filter() but it didn't work. so I created this code to search a list. it works but when I delete some letters the list gets stuck at the last result and never updates.

eg list: hello, hi, han, solo

when i type 'h'  then hello, hi, and han show up.

when i add an 'e' so thats its 'he' only hello shows

when i delete the e, han and hi do not come up again.

```
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
     final ArrayList<String> finalItems = mItems;
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }



    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        ArrayList<String> searchedItems = retainsSearched(mItems, s.toString());
        adapter.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < searchedItems.size(); i++) {
            adapter.add(searchedItems.get(i));
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

};

public  ArrayList<String> retainsSearched(ArrayList<String> mItems2, String term) {
    ArrayList<String> stations = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < mItems2.size(); i++) {
        if (mItems2.get(i).toLowerCase().startsWith(term.toLowerCase())) {
            stations.add(mItems2.get(i));
        }
    }
    return stations;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when i type 'h' then hello, hi, and han show up. when i add an 'e' so
>   thats its 'he' only hello shows when i delete the e, han and hi do not
>   come up again.

That is most likely happening because the `mItems` list that you use in the `TextWatcher` is the list that is backing your adapter so by modifying it(when filtering and clearing/re adding items in the adapter) you always reduce the number of items available in the adapter, the items that you "see" each time you filter the list.

Instead try to make a copy of your initial items(`mItems` list) in the adapter and always do the filtering by testing the items in that copy(but don't modify it, just add the matched items to the adapter).

Again, you should use the `getFilter()` method.

Edit:

```
ArrayList<String> searchedItems = retainsSearched(s.toString()); 
// ...

public  ArrayList<String> retainsSearched(ArrayList<String term) {
    ArrayList<String> stations = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < copyList.size(); i++) {
        if (copyList.get(i).toLowerCase().startsWith(term.toLowerCase())) {
            stations.add(copyList.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried creating copy of mItems as soon as I populated it in onCreate() and I used that copy instead but the problem remains

Comment: @user521180 How did you copy the list ? Did you use `ArrayList<String> copyList = new ArrayList<String>(mItems);`. See my edited answer on how to use the `copyList`.

Comment: wow `ArrayList<String> copyList = new ArrayList<String>(mItems);` worked! i was doing `ArrayList<String> copyList = mItems;` and I think i even tried `ArrayList<String> copyList = new ArrayList<String>(); copyList = mItems;` why didn't that work?. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user521180 `copyList = mItems` doesn't work because that line just makes the `copyList` and `mItems` references to point to the same list object. `ArrayList<String> copyList = new ArrayList<String>(mItems);` on the other hand copies all the elements from the `mItems` to `copyList` so you end up with two different objects.